# Rewriting URLs with query strings and preserving them

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

straight to the issue - I MUST preserve link structure as follows, otherwise the baby squirrels die:

```
website.com/blog.html?comments=%id%
```

where the `%id%` stands for ID of post basicaly, that corresponds with the post IDs in my WordPress installation. So, is it possible to somehow get to the `%id%` thing and use it as a variable to pass to `somewordpresssite.com/?p=%id%` either through .htaccess or the Rewrite API itself, I don't really care. Today I went through a lot of tutorials, forums, hints, tried to write code in .htaccess (basic rules with `${QUERYSTRING}` work, but WordPress overrides them with it own ones, and it looks mixed) and nothing worked. I got to

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^blog.html[^/]comments=([0-9]{4})$', 'index.php?&p=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

which would accepte even

```
website.com/blog.htmlDcomments=%id%
```

and that'll do perfectly! But when there is a query (basicaly question mark), everything breaks. I'd be really glad if anyone could help. Thank you.

Comment: [Cortex](http://cortex.zoomlab.it/)? Specifically this [feature](http://cortex.zoomlab.it/docs/routes-basics.html#merge-or-ignore-query-string).

Comment: Can it be done somehow during the actual creation of permalink? Could I even change some code before the creation of permalink in WordPress source? Thank you.